# Testing Ionic Apps with jest-angular: Queries do not work on elements created by Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, jestjs

I am trying to test an App written with Ionic/angular using jest/angular.
However it seems very basic selectors do not work.
Basically it seems all elements added by Ionic to generate the UI are not accessible.
I've created a small repository to reproduce the issue, showing the behavior on the example of an ion-searchbar which contains an input somewhere inside that I want to select to e.g. check its value.

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Clone https://github.com/pct-cclausen/ionic-jest-example
2. npm install
3. npm run test
4. See file apps/test-app/src/app/app.component.spec.ts:

```js
 it('finds the input inside the ion-searchbar', async () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);

    // sleep is necessary to make sure the dom is hydrated by Ionic.
    // I've not found another way to do this.
    await sleep(100);

    // Show the status of the HTML. This skips shadow dom elements,
    // but they are not important in this scenario
    // Notice there is an input element inside the ion-searchbar
    phl(fixture);

    // the searchbar itself can be found
    expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('ion-searchbar'))).not.toBeNull();

    // the input that was created by ionic inside the searchbar is not accessible,
    // even though phl was able to print it
    expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'))).not.toBeNull();
  });
```